# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'modules' does not exist in type 'ModuleMetadata'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I just upgraded all packages, specially TypeScript from 2.5.2 to the 3.8.3 and I'm getting this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ modules: (typeof OrmModule)[];
>   controllers: (typeof AppController)[]; components: (typeof
>   ConfigurationService | typeof LoggingService | typeof
>   MessagingService)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ModuleMetadata'.   Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and 'modules' does not exist in type 'ModuleMetadata'.
>
> 19   modules: [OrmModule, AdminModule, CrmModule, EmrModule],

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

import { AuthenticationMiddleware } from './authentication/tokenhandler';
import { MulterMiddleware } from './common/middlewares/multer';

import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { OrmModule } from '../orm/orm.module';
import { CrmModule } from './crm/crm.module';
import { EmrModule } from './emr/emr.module';
import { ConfigurationService } from './common/services/configuration';
import { LoggingService } from './common/services/logging';
import { MessagingService } from './common/services/messaging';

@Module({
  modules: [OrmModule, AdminModule, CrmModule, EmrModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  components: [ConfigurationService, LoggingService, MessagingService]
})

export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(AuthenticationMiddleware)
      .with(  // routes that will be excluded.
        { path: '/leads/open', method: RequestMethod.POST },
        { path: '/', method: RequestMethod.GET },
        { path: '/documents/upload', method: RequestMethod.POST },
      ).forRoutes( //routes that will be included
        { path: '/*', method: RequestMethod.ALL },
        { path: '/*/*', method: RequestMethod.ALL }
      );
    consumer.apply(MulterMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '/images/:leadId', method: RequestMethod.POST },
            { path: '/documents/:leadId', method: RequestMethod.POST },
            { path: '/examination/stylist/:leadId', method: RequestMethod.POST },
            { path: '/examination/stylist/:leadId/:id', method: RequestMethod.PUT }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `modules: []` for `imports: []`

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this may be an answer to the question, can you provide a bit more elaboration as to why it solves the problem? Perhaps include a link to docs or some sort of explanation. Thanks.